# How to reference every UILabel in an application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'd like to change the font of every `UILabel` in every view of my application without coding every single one (about 50). How would i go about doing this?

Specifically, i'd like to know how to reference all `UILabels`.

Thanks

Comment: Are labels created programmatically or IB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can easily be handled by the new iOS 5 appearance API. Appearance API allows you to change the appearance of the control throughout the application.

Take a look at my screenshot below: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L63CU2T7DBE&list=UUKvDySsrOVgUgRLhWHeyHJA&index=4&feature=plcp

This might work:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:56]];

    [[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UIButton class], nil] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:10]];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of help. One issue though is when i write: `[[UILabel appearance] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"myFont" size:34]];`, all text is changed to `myFont` including `UIButtons`.

Comment: I know you can provide filters on appearance where you can say do not do anything if it is contained within certain control. Let me see if I can find that code.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIAppearance

Comment: setFont is now deprecated. Does anyone know an alternative?

Comment: `setFont` on `UIButton` is deprecated, but the OP's code calls it on a prototype object of type `UILabel` (the framework actually uses a subclass called `UIButtonLabel`).  However, the `UIButton` code which creates a `UIButtonLabel` doesn't appear to respect `UIAppearance` containment.